# How to remove html tag while fetching data from JSON Url

Tags: android, json, android-studio, textview

This is my code it get the json from the url and the json contain some html tags like `(<p>,</p>,<br>)` while fetching the data the tags also displaying in textview so my question is how to remove those tag without lineseperator or replace method.

I have Uploaded the picture of the output it contains html tag while displaying i dont want those to display .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIlgl.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    private Button w_sharee;

    private static String url = "http://mantras.happylife.in/mantras_api";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();

    }

    class ItemList implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)view;
            TextView ti = (TextView)vg.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView de = (TextView)vg.findViewById(R.id.desc);

            String selected = ti.getText().toString() + de.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,selected);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share via"));

//            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ti.getText().toString() + de.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }


    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray hotboxs = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    for (int i = 0; i < hotboxs.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = hotboxs.getJSONObject(i);


//                        if (c.get("configurationId").equals(7)) {



//                        String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                        String title = c.getString("title");
                        String desc = c.getString("desc");
//
//                        desc= desc.replace("<br />", lineSep);
//                        desc= desc.replace("<p>", lineSep);
//                        desc= desc.replace("</p>", lineSep);
//                        desc= desc.replace("<li>", lineSep);
//                        desc= desc.replace("</li>", lineSep);



                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                            contact.put("title", title);
                            contact.put("desc", desc);
                            contactList.add(contact);
//                        }

                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                   MainActivity.this, contactList,
                  R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"title","desc"}, new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.desc});
          lv.setAdapter(adapter);
          lv.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemList());


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: set Html text instead of text.issue will be solved.

Comment: can you edit in the code

Comment: Please check::  `ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"title","desc"}, new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.desc}){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

                textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(contactList.get(position).get(position)));
                return textView;
            }
        };`

Comment: Its not working dood

Comment: Please simplify your code sample. Only show the relevant part of your question